# Is there a way to change app store territory for an Android beta tester on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I want to test a in app purchase currency conversion based on a user's country of use. Is this possible through internal/alpha/beta testing on Google Play?

For example, for iPhone beta testers, you can set up a Sandbox user, and set the Sandbox user's "app store territory." This makes a tester's account act as though the user is accessing the app from that territory.

Is there a similar (and simple) way to do this on Android/Google Play?

Thanks!

Comment: yes you can change from your play store account you will get the option in  Pricing & distribution section

Comment: @MilanPansuriya, I'm not sure which option you are referring to. I don't want to change the country where the app is available. I want to test the app from my device as though it were using the app from a foreign country. Is there something I'm missing from this section?